# Toolbar is not fully hidden on scroll

Tags: android, android-toolbar

These code work fine to me, but the toolbar is not fully hidden on scrolling. I tried lot of things to solve it but i still have the same issue.

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagesanimation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />





        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In MainActivity.java in onCreate:

```
 CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");

        NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById (R.id.nestedScrollView);
        scrollView.setFillViewport (true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to totally hide the toolbar, then you should try to set
 `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"` in your CollapsingToolbarLayout